# Check DateInString format before formatting

Tags: java, date, format, compare, simpledateformat

My incoming data  will have Dates in String which I am supposed to format to the following format "dd/MM/yyyy". I am able to convert the date to the correct format with:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //New Format

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); //old format
String dateInString = "2013/10/07" //string might be in different format

try{
  Date date = sdf2.parse(dateInString);       
  System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
}

catch (ParseException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I have strings in different format such as 2013/10/07, 07/10/2013, 10/07/2013, 7 Jul 13. How do I compare them before formatting it individually?

I found this [Check date format before parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608049/check-date-format-before-parsing) pretty similar but I cannot comprehend it.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you have a problem understanding the answer?

Comment: Hey, i encounter errors with some..
"2013/10/07" work perfectly, however, others will output a different date.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an utility class, which has a list of all supported formats and a method that tries to convert a given `String` object to `Date`.

```
public class DateUtil {
     private static List<SimpleDateFormat> dateFormats;

     static {
         dateFormats = new ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat>();
         dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"));
         dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy"));
         dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
         dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
         // add more, if needed.
     }

     public static Date convertToDate(String input) throws Exception {
         Date result = null;
         if (input == null) {
             return null; // or throw an Exception, if you wish
         }

         for (SimpleDateFormat sdf : dateFormats) {
            try {
                result = sdf.parse(input);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //caught if the format doesn't match the given input String
            }
            if (result != null) {
                break;
            }
         }
         if (result == null) {
           throw new Exception("The provided date is not of supported format");
         }
         return result;
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However if my string is "07/10/2013" It outputs Tue Apr 04 00:00:00 SGT 13. Which is a different date.